# Informix Parser Stacks Full

Tags: php, sql-server, informix, linked-server

I have established a linked database connection with AVAYA thru Informix and SQL server.
And the connection works fine, also I have made web apps that gets data from it and moves it a mirror table so I can work with those data.
I also made some apps that query with `SELECT` statements only.

Everything works fine until recently. I wasn't able to fetch data from my linked server and Informix prompts an error of `Informix parser stacks full`.
I've done research to fix it but can't seem to find one. What I did was to restart the whole database on SQL server and everything working again.

I would want to know more about this and how I can avoid this happening again.

Comment: You will need to be a lot more precise about where that error message comes from.  It doesn't look like a native Informix message (it should have an error number associated with it, and that should be negative), but I don't know where PHP, Avaya, and SQL Server fit into the system.  As it stands, the question is unanswerable.  Also, if it was working until recently and then stopped, you should look at what changed recently.

Comment: Finally (for now), if restarting SQL Server broke the log jam, that suggests the problem is up-stream of Informix (assuming that PHP/Avaya talks to SQL Server, which talks to Informix via the linked server mechanism).  I could believe that there was something in SQL Server which was parsing the SQL destined for Informix that went wrong.  I've no specific evidence for that, but it seems plausible.

Comment: Thank you for that insight! The changes made was when I made a scheduled task with `Task Scheduler` running my my batch file(.bat) to run my SQL file to update a certain table. It runs every 15mins. And I think this is what causes my problem. I made a simple update statement on that file.